# How to create the EAR file based on the configuration files using maven?

Tags: maven

Could you please advise me , how to create  the EAR file based on the environment configuration using maven build tool?

I have given below my project folder  structure.

```
MyProjectApp
  --- pom.xml

MyEAR
   -- src
       -- config
            -- prod
           --  qa
            -- dev
   --pom.xml
MyWeb
  -- src
      -- java
           --main
  --pom.xml
```

(MyEar and MyWeb are modules) or children of MyProjectApp.

I am expecting the below EAR files.

MyProjectApp_PROD.ear - which contains only the production config information

MyProjectApp_DEV.ear - which  contains only the DEV config information.

Regards
Vasanth D

Comment: `prod`, `qa` and `dev` are properties files or folder with some content? In your `MyEar`, are you using maven ear plugin?

Comment: Yes , i am using maven ear plugin , prod and qa  folders ,and it contains .properties files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven profiles to separate environments information. So, you can put in you `pom.xml` properties like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>dev</environment>
            <property-one>value-one</property-one>
            <property-two>value-two</property-two>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>prod</environment>
            <property-one>value-one</property-one>
            <property-two>value-two</property-two>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If `prod`, `qa` and `dev` are properties files, then you can use it as [filters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to get environment information to generate you `application.xml`:

```
<build>
    <filter>/path/to/${environment}.properties</filter>
</build>
```

To generate EAR files with the name you want, you can set the final name in build like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>MyProjectApp_${environment}</finalName>
</build>
```

You can also use [`maven-ear-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin), something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>MyWeb</artifactId>
                <moduleId>MyWeb</moduleId>
                <contextRoot>/portal</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
        <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, to generate **prod** package, do: `mvn clean package -Pprod`

And **dev** package, do: `mvn clean package -Pdev`

You can also turn an profile active by default.

If you need generate both in same build execution, take a look in [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

If this does not works to you, put more information, such as `pom.xml` content, configs, etc.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this is very helpful and saves my time.